# Filename encoding switched to UTF-8 by tar when untaring to Windows share

Tags: mount, tar, cifs, encoding

We have different Magento installations (webshop) that allows images to be added to a product freely. When an image is added to a product, the file is named in a specific way that sometimes encorporates special characters (for instance German umlauts).

In the one case I'm currently looking into the filenames are encoded in latin1. I can see that by doing `ls` into a file, then reading the file via `vim`. Using the `fileencoding=latin1`, the umlauts are displayed correctly.

Now, these Magento installations are backed up by `tar`, `7zip` and `ccrypt` (in that order). Unpacking those on linux gives the same filenames in the same encoding.

We now have a share on a Windows system where we would want to put the untarred Magento installation on. While untarring however, a number of error messages pop up in regard to the umlaut file names:

```
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/12063-sportsto\337d\344mpfer-hinten.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/15240-kunststoffkotfl\374gel-detail-vorne.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/14300-fl\374gel.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/15240-41kotfl\374gel-kunststoff-vorne.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/citr\366n.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/2cv6-ma\337e-1.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/2cv6-ma\337e.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
tar: var/magento_webs/customer/media/import/images/11076-vorschalld\344mpfer.jpg: Kann open nicht ausführen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

(It roughly translates to `Cannot execute open: File or directory not found`)

Now, looking at the filenames tar lists, I can see that tar seems to try to create UTF-8 encoded filenames (\337 looks that way). However, the mount point has been made available via (from `etc/fstab`):

```
//192.168.0.111/share   /mnt/share      cifs    username=myusername,noperm,sec=ntlm,codepage=cp850       0       0
```

I'm not sure why these file names cannot be written to the share in a fashion that preserves the umlaut encoding. Am I missing another option (is codepage the wrong option for this)?

Edit 1: I can recreate something similar by SSHing into the linux box, setting the `Remote character set` of the connection to `ISO8859-15`, changing to the share directory and `touch`ing a file with an umlaut:

```
touch: kann â\244â nicht berÃŒhren: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

(Can't touch X: File or directory not found)

Edit 2: First try of a solution

I'e added `iocharset=utf8` to the mount options, remounted the share, but got the exact same problems with the same files. Strangely enough, using `mount` (which usually prints all the options mount points have been mounted with) doesn't print the `iocharset` option (neither with `utf8` nor with `cp850` as the setting).

Answer (score 0):

Some time in the past (I believe between version 2.0 or so), mount.cifs lost the "codepage=" option and put everything in the "iocharset=" option.

You should be fine with

```
//host/share /mnt/share cifs username=blah,noperm,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't change anything. I've updated the problem with  results and findings.

Comment: Oh, right, I hate that. You also have to have the share offered with UTF-8 enabled. The SMB server itself is Windows, I take it?

Comment: Yes, it's a Windows share. It's on the host, while the linux box is a guest inside VirtualBox.

Comment: Also, check that nls_utf8 is either loaded as a module or compiled in on the client (it probably is since you can see the characters, but just to be sure...)

Comment: Loaded are both nls_utf8 and nls_cp850.